# Create control from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

i have this code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += (s, ev) => show();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void show()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("aaaaaa");

        PictureBox load = new PictureBox();
        load.BackColor = Color.White;
        load.Width = this.Width;
        load.Height = this.Height;
        load.Left = 0;
        load.Top = 0;
        load.Name = "load";

        this.Controls.Add(load);
        load.BringToFront();

        MessageBox.Show("bbbbb");
    }
```

The PictureBox will not be created and the "bbbbb" MessageBox do not appear.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that you create the controls in another `Thread`than your GUI runs in. `BackgroundWorker` has an event `RunworkerCompleted` which is triggered after the `DoWork` eventhandler is completed. `RunworkerCompleted` then runs in the `Thread` that called `DoWork` (in your case the main thread). So you do all non GUI related work in `DoWork` and GUI stuff in `RunWorkerCompleted`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += (s, ev) => calculate();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ev) => show();
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void calculate()
{
     // Do some heavy work
     Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

private void show()
{
    MessageBox.Show("aaaaaa");

    PictureBox load = new PictureBox();
    load.BackColor = Color.White;
    load.Width = this.Width;
    load.Height = this.Height;
    load.Left = 0;
    load.Top = 0;
    load.Name = "load";

    this.Controls.Add(load);
    load.BringToFront();

    MessageBox.Show("bbbbb");
}
```